# check is nested struct bool flags are set

Tags: c, struct, flags

In an api I have to work with there are deeply nested c structs which are all tightly packed in consecutive memory. If I want to find out if a certain property is enables, the most obvious way is

```
bool hasValidData = myInstance.data->fieldValidity.isReallyValid
```

Is there a more terse way of checking if this boolean is indeed true or false? I have to check the joined true-ness of several of these values and this becomes very tedious and long

Comment: Write a `hasValidData` function?

Comment: There's no easy way to loop over struct members. So all you can do is write a bunch of tests and combine them with `&&`.

Comment: Could you create an array of addresses to the field of interest then loop over those?  Write a local macro that takes the field name as input CHECK(isReallyValid) or whatever is different for each field.

Comment: What are the types of all variables involved?  `I have to check the joined true-ness of several of these values` Which values? `myInstance.data->fieldValidity.anotherReallyValid`? `myInstance.data->anotherFieldValidity.isReallyValid`? `myInstance.anotherData->fieldValidity.isReallyValid`? `anotherInstance.Data->fieldValidity.isReallyValid`? What are the types at each level, and are they the same in "several of these values"?

Comment: only the most nested one are bools, the others are structs